# Unable to see the VS2013 Designer due to Fluent DLL

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, fluent

Firstly, let me say yes i have done some research. but now im just frustrated as.

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache\didkffin.1gk\ecny11ys.s1u\Fluent.dll
    An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.

So clearly this isnt a network location... what the hell?

I have tried right clicking the DLL and clicking unblock. it just create a new temp directory with a copy of the DLL.

I have set to embedd interops type. that doesnt work either.
I have set Copy to local as false. no help there either.

i have put this code into the App.Config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1"/>
    </startup>
<runtime>         
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
  </runtime> 
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Windows.Data" switchName="SourceSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <remove name="Default" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

And yet i still have the issue.

```
Mainwindow.xaml
<Fluent:MetroWindow x:Class="Enterprise.MainWindow" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Fluent="clr-namespace:Fluent;assembly=Fluent"
        Title="MainWindow"  Style="{DynamicResource MetroWindowStyle}">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Fluent:MetroWindow>


 Mainwindow.xaml.cs
using Fluent;
namespace Enterprise
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Yes the aseembly is loaded.

```
These two errors exists even tho the project compiles and runs
Error   1   The name "MetroWindow" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Fluent;assembly=Fluent".  
Error   2   The type 'Fluent:MetroWindow' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
```

Im stumped. can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone that might have this issue, i have resolved it.

Step 1: remove the references in your project.

Step 2: Rename the obj folder

Step 3: Open your .proj file. Find the reference it will look something like this.

```
<Reference Include="Fluent, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e436e32a8c5546f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\Dev\Assets\Ribbon\Fluent.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

and

```
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\Dev\Assets\Ribbon\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Delete both of these from your file. thats the whole  tag

Step 4: Relaunch Visual studio.
Step 5: Re-Add the references.